# Traefik 2.2 makes lots of /health calls simultaneously for only 1 backend

Tags: traefik

I have 10 routers with 1 service, the service only has 1 server. (I have simplified the example)

The routers have individual files each one, where N a number from 1 to 10.

`/etc/traefik/projectN_develop_intern.yaml`

```
http:
  routers:
    projectN_develop_intern:
      service: cluster_develop-cluster
      entryPoints:
        - https
      rule: PathPrefix(`/project-N/`) && Host(`develop.my-domain.com`)
      middlewares: []
      priority: 1
```

I have 1 service with 1 health:

`/etc/traefik/conf.d/cluster_develop-cluster.yaml`

```
http:
  services:
    cluster_develop-cluster:
      loadBalancer:
        healthCheck:
          path: /health
          timeout: 3s
          interval: 5s
        servers:
          - url: 'http://127.0.0.1:81/'
        passHostHeader: true
```

I'm expecting that traefik only makes 1 health call every 3 seconds to the service server, but I'm receiving 10 health calls every 10 seconds, one per router.

[image]

I'm using **traefik 2.2**, but this happened in **traefik 1.7** too, that is the reason we migrated to traefik 2:

```
[root@centos ~]# traefik version
Version:      2.2.2
Codename:     chevrotin
Go version:   go1.14.4
Built:        2020-07-08T15:30:29Z
OS/Arch:      linux/386
```

This is the starting log:

```
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=info msg="Traefik version 2.2.2 built on 2020-07-08T15:30:29Z"
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=debug msg="Static configuration loaded {\"global\":{},\"serversTransport\":{\"maxIdleConnsPerHost\":200},\"entryPoints\":{\"http\":{\"address\":\":80\",\"transport\":{\"lifeCycle\":{\"gr$
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=info msg="\nStats collection is disabled.\nHelp us improve Traefik by turning this feature on :)\nMore details on: https://docs.traefik.io/contributing/data-collection/\n"
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=info msg="Starting provider aggregator.ProviderAggregator {}"
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=debug msg="Start TCP Server" entryPointName=https
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=debug msg="Start TCP Server" entryPointName=http
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=debug msg="Start TCP Server" entryPointName=traefik
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=info msg="Starting provider *file.Provider {\"directory\":\"/etc/traefik/conf.d\",\"watch\":true}"
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=info msg="Starting provider *traefik.Provider {}"
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider file: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"project1_develop_extern\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"https\"],\"service\":\"cluster_develop-cluster\",\"rule$
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider internal: {\"http\":{\"routers\":{\"api\":{\"entryPoints\":[\"traefik\"],\"service\":\"api@internal\",\"rule\":\"PathPrefix(`/api`)\",\"pr$
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=debug msg="No store is defined to add the certificate XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, it will be added to the default store."
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=debug msg="Adding certificate for domain(s) *.our-domain.com,our-domain.com"
time="2020-07-16T10:03:10+02:00" level=debug msg="No default certificate, generating one"
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=https routerName=project2_develop_extern@file serviceName=cluster_develop-cluster middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" entryPointName=https routerName=project2_develop_extern@file serviceName=cluster_develop-cluster
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://api-node3.our-domain.com" serverName=0 entryPointName=https routerName=project2_develop_extern@file serviceName=cluster_develop-cluster
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating server 1 http://api-node4.our-domain.com" serverName=1 serviceName=cluster_develop-cluster entryPointName=https routerName=project2_develop_extern@file
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware cluster_develop-cluster" middlewareType=TracingForwarder routerName=project2_develop_extern@file entryPointName=https middlewareName=tra$
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" middlewareType=Pipelining entryPointName=https routerName=project3_develop_intern@file serviceName=cluster_develop-cluster middlewareName=pipelining
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" entryPointName=https routerName=project3_develop_intern@file serviceName=cluster_develop-cluster
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://api-node3.our-domain.com" entryPointName=https routerName=project3_develop_intern@file serviceName=cluster_develop-cluster serverName=0
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating server 1 http://api-node4.our-domain.com" serverName=1 entryPointName=https routerName=project3_develop_intern@file serviceName=cluster_develop-cluster
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware cluster_develop-cluster" middlewareName=tracing entryPointName=https routerName=project3_develop_intern@file middlewareType=TracingForwarder
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" entryPointName=https routerName=project4_production_extern@file serviceName=cluster_production-cluster middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" routerName=project4_production_extern@file serviceName=cluster_production-cluster entryPointName=https
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating server 0 http://api-node1.our-domain.com" entryPointName=https routerName=project4_production_extern@file serviceName=cluster_production-cluster serverName=0
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating server 1 http://api-node2.our-domain.com" entryPointName=https routerName=project4_production_extern@file serverName=1 serviceName=cluster_production-cluster
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating server 2 http://api-node3.our-domain.com" entryPointName=https routerName=project4_production_extern@file serviceName=cluster_production-cluster serverName=2
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating server 3 http://api-node4.our-domain.com" entryPointName=https routerName=project4_production_extern@file serviceName=cluster_production-cluster serverName=3
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Added outgoing tracing middleware cluster_production-cluster" middlewareName=tracing middlewareType=TracingForwarder entryPointName=https routerName=project4_production_exter$
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating middleware" serviceName=cluster_develop-cluster middlewareName=pipelining middlewareType=Pipelining routerName=project5_develop_extern@file entryPointName=https
time="2020-07-16T10:03:11+02:00" level=debug msg="Creating load-balancer" routerName=project5_develop_extern@file entryPointName=https serviceName=cluster_develop-cluster
```

I think that traefik creates multiple balancers for every router and when fetching server urls, it returns the health url repeated.

There is more info in the github issue: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/7043